# Spring Dynamic List Binding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a typical scenario - I have read many articles on this and dynamic addition seems to work fine. I could not get elegant solution for dynamic delete.

1. A Web Form is simulating a User. User can have name and List of phoneNumbers.
2. phoneNumbers can be added dynamically using Javascript at client side.
3. Dynamic addition of phoneNumber into phoneNumbers is not a problem - Thanks to LazyList / AutoPopulatingList.
4. Dynamic Deletion is kind of an issue. Let's say the web form was rendered with phoneNumbers as {1,3,5,7,9}. Using Javascript the user removes {1,3} without submitting the form. Now when the form is submitted user.phoneNumbers should automatically have {5,7,9}.

Somehow, Spring MVC just doesn't contain the updated list. I am using annotation based controllers.

Gurus any help?

Comment: by "Spring MVC just doesn't contain the updated list" do you mean that the object created from your form doesn't have phone numbers removed? Perhaps you haven't removed the form item from the DOM properly.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do as follows

**For each removed PhoneNumber object, i do a Ajax request**. A PhoneNumberRepository takes care of deleting the PhoneNumber

```
@Repository
public class PhoneNumberRepositoryImpl implements PhoneNumberRepository {

    public void removePhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        // code goes here
    }

}
```

This way, you user will contain only PhoneNumber that has not been removed.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ideha) you can see **how i remove / add** collection based property. It works fine!

regards,

Comment: I used the same AJAX approach in one project. Sent an ajax delete request and if it was successfull I removed the row via DOM calls.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same thing with Autopopulating list.

I use a dojo ajax call to 
1) dojo.destroy the dom with the removed list value, then 
2) on the server I do list.remove(index).

The value in the list ends up being null but the index and the size of the list remain the same size (the largest size possible ie: if 4 ajax add calls the list will remain a size of 4 even if one or several remove calls are completed).

Were you able to figure out why this was happening?